# Rails 5 "no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer" for double nested has_many attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I keep getting the error `no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer` when trying to create/update a `Form` model via a form. I've narrowed it down to something to do with `actions_attributes` in the `form_params`. `trigger_attributes` works fine if `actions_attributes` is removed. I suspect it has something to do with the enum field, double nested attributes, and/or the `has_many` relationship, but not sure.

Any ideas on what could be causing this error?

Running Rails 5.0.x and Ruby 2.3.x, with the relevant models and controller below.

```
class Form < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :rule
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :rule
end

class Rule < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :trigger
  has_many :actions
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :trigger
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :actions
end

class Trigger < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :rule
  enum name: [:example]
end

class Actions < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :rule
  enum name: [:example]
end

class FormsController < ApplicationController
  ...
  private

  def form_params
      params.require(:form).permit(
        :title,
        :description,
        rule_attributes: [
                           trigger_attributes: [:name],
                           actions_attributes: [:name]
                         ]
      ) 
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I got this to work by changing `actions_attributes:` to `actions:` under `def form_params`, as well as making the relevant change to the form, changing `fields_for :actions_attributes` to `fields_for :actions`.

I'm often confused when to use `_attributes` and when not to. If anyone has information about when to use which, I would appreciate it if you could provide a link to the information in the comments. Thanks.